# ASP.NET session variables naming conventions

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, naming-conventions

Is there any convention for naming session variables in ASP.NET?

Options that come to my mind:

```
Session["myValue"] = "value";
Session["MyValue"] = "value";
Session["my_value"] = "value";
Session["MY_VALUE"] = "value";
```

Comment: generally Microsoft Partners use camel casing

Comment: Most common: Session["MyValue"] = "value";

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMO, it is important to apply the DRY principle:

```
public class SessionVariables
{
    public const string MyStoredSessionVariable = "MyStoredSessionVariable";
    ...
}
```

and then:

```
Session[SessionVariables.MyStoredSessionVariable] = ...
```

I don't think it matters much which string literal you use, as long as it is unique enough and you do it in a consistent way, like others have mentioned.

Answer (score 4):

There aren't any formal naming conventions but you could consider using an enum so that you don't have any string literals which 1) makes it easier to remember the names of your keys and 2) makes it impossible to have a runtime error because you can't have a typo in your key name.

e.g.

```
public enum SessionKey
{
   FirstName,
   LastName,
   BusinessId
}
```

then do:

```
    Session[SessionKeys.FirstName.ToString()] = "Rob";
```

or create yourself a SessionHelper class that that makes the whole process a lot tidier:

```
public static class SessionHelper
    {
        public static void SetSessionKey(SessionKey sessionKey, object value)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Session.Add(sessionKey.ToString(), value.ToString());
        }

        public static String GetSessionKey(SessionKey sessionKey)
        {
            return HttpContext.Current.Session[sessionKey.ToString()] as string;
        }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing like a convention. Its a convention which is shared by developers or framed by the project team so that it becomes easy for everyone. 

Like you have mentioned, my organisation uses upper case with underscores.

Comment: As @GuruC mentioned, there isn't such thing as a universal convention for this. Each company/developer may have a different way to name their sessions. The company I work at sometimes uses upper case strings exposed as constants in a static class. Sometimes (or some projects) we use a Dictionary with an enum as key and the value as the actual name of the session.

Answer (score 0):

CamelCase is a good option.

Session["MyValue"] = "value";

CamelCase reference:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase

Comment: This is actually PascalCase not camelCase (camels only have humps in the middle)

Comment: CamelCase is correct. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase

Comment: Seems it depends which school you went too - http://cplus.about.com/od/learnc/ss/csharpclasses_5.htm what do you call thisVariationThen? The Wiki link you provided also has some fairly substantial caveats that support my statement...

Comment: The Wikipedia article says: that the practice is known by many other names, the most common of which is pascal case.

Comment: It also says - The first letter of a camel case compound may or may not be capitalized. For clarity, this article calls the two alternatives upper camel case and lower camel case. Some people and organizations use the term camel case only for lower camel case. Other synonyms include: (among them Pascal Case) I'm not disagreeing with you - but using only the terminology Camel Case is ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

**Usually these conventions are decided by the team to keep consistency through out the code, but if suppose you are extending or customizing existing code then its better to follow that existing written code is being following.
Another thing is that, if you want to decide which convention to follow, so usually for Constants capital naming convention is followed, and else Camel notation is followed for better readability.**